# Object Tag downloading file instead of embedding

Tags: html

I have an object tag like this:

```
<object type="text/plain" data="http://www.theurl.com/thefile"></object>
```

The file I am accessing has no file-extension, but I would like to embed it as plain text. However, this code just causes a download of the file to start.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: What headers are being returned with the response?  "File extensions" don't mean anything in HTTP, but headers are very important.

Comment: The only headers being returned are:


`Content-Length:62
Content-Type:text/plain
Pragma:no-cache`

Comment: do you use php in your page?

Comment: No, it is straight html and javascript

Comment: I think using iframes could help you as well

Comment: @sliptype did you ever find an answer for this?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the built-in fetch() method and access the file with .then() afterwards.

```
<script>
    fetch("http://www.theurl.com/thefile")
    .then((r)=>{r.text().then((d)=>{console.log(d)})});
</script>
```

But that throws the "CORS"-error so you have to enable Cross-Origin for the hosted document. Otherwise it forbids you to fetch it.

Here is a working example of fetch():

```
<script>
    fetch('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/77/Delete_key1.jpg')
    .then((r)=>{r.text().then((d)=>{console.log(d)})});
</script>
```